# SparklyR removing a tbl from Spark Context

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr

Similar to: [SparklyR removing a Table from Spark Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025094/sparklyr-removing-a-table-from-spark-context), but different because:

The above question asks how to remove a "table" from spark, here created by the `copy_to` function. If the `spark_read_csv()` function is used instead it appears that there is a difference in class.

```
my_csv <- spark_read_csv("name", sc)
db_drop_table(my_table)
```

returns:

```
Error in UseMethod("db_drop_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'db_drop_table' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_spark', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
```

Which indicates further that the object created here is not a `table` but a `tbl`, Hadleys data type of choice.

Therefore, how can I remove a specific `tbl` and only that `tbl` from the memory/session without exiting the full session?

Bonus: is there a button in RStudio Server interface that I've missed that will perform this process for me? I can't see on obvious way to do this in the spark connection tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `sparklyr`:

- Creates temporary views -  this just creates corresponding entries in the metastore but doesn't occupy any resources
- By default eagerly caches the data (`memory` parameter for reader is set to `TRUE`).

You can remove tables from metastore using `dropView` method:

```
sc %>% spark_session() %>% invoke("catalog") %>%
  invoke("dropTempView", "my_table")
```

or clear cache with `clearCache` method:

```
sc %>% spark_session() %>% invoke("catalog") %>% 
  invoke("clearCache")
```

Unless you're worried about the name clashes you should probably focus on the second one, although I'd recommend avoiding eager caching, unless it is strictly necessary.

Comment: 2 for 2, thanks a lot. If it's not obvious I'm just starting with all the spark stuff, could you expand on the difference between the two in simple terms please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DBI` package to resolve the issue.

```
library("DBI")
dbGetQuery(sc,"drop table if exists my_table")
```