# in sparklyr ,how to drop a existing object (table ) thanks

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

In R/Sparklyr,there is a spark table 'iris_csv', i want to drop it, but `dplyr::db_drop_table(sc,'iris_csv')` failed, anyone can help? Thanks!

Here is the error message as attached image .

[image]

Comment: Please share errors, code and data as **plain text** and not as images. Thank you.

Comment: @user438383
 Here is the error message,Thanks !      Error in UseMethod("db_drop_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'db_drop_table' applied to an object of class "c('spark_connection', 'spark_shell_connection', 'DBIConnection')"

Comment: Use the workaround at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533664/